# Runtime Hints for Spring Boot 3 AOT with jOOQ 3.18+

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, jooq, graalvm-native-image, aot

Starting a native Spring Boot image with an application that uses jOOQ 3.18+ results in

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at org.jooq.impl.DefaultBinding.binding(DefaultBinding.java:487)
        at org.jooq.impl.DefaultBinding.binding(DefaultBinding.java:329)
        at org.jooq.impl.DefaultDataType.<init>(DefaultDataType.java:391)
        at org.jooq.impl.DefaultDataType.<init>(DefaultDataType.java:335)
        at org.jooq.impl.DefaultDataType.<init>(DefaultDataType.java:331)
        at org.jooq.impl.DefaultDataType.<init>(DefaultDataType.java:319)
        at org.jooq.impl.ArrayDataType.<init>(ArrayDataType.java:63)
        at org.jooq.impl.AbstractDataType.getArrayDataType(AbstractDataType.java:660)
        at org.jooq.impl.DefaultDataType.getArrayDataType(DefaultDataType.java:136)
        at org.jooq.impl.DefaultDataType.<init>(DefaultDataType.java:396)
        at org.jooq.impl.DefaultDataType.<init>(DefaultDataType.java:335)
        at org.jooq.impl.DefaultDataType.<init>(DefaultDataType.java:331)
        at org.jooq.impl.DefaultDataType.<init>(DefaultDataType.java:315)
        at org.jooq.impl.BuiltInDataType.<init>(BuiltInDataType.java:60)
        at org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.<clinit>(SQLDataType.java:621)
        ... 86 common frames omitted
```

After investigation, the `reflect-config.json` from Spring Boot 3 misses an entry for `java.time.Year` which is used in `org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.java` on line `621` (which matches the trace) as:

```java
...
    public static final DataType<Year> YEAR = new BuiltInDataType<>(Year.class, "year");
...
```

This was added in jOOQ for supporting a MySQL type.

To have this type available in the built native image, I have tried to add a hint to the compiler based on the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/native-image.html#native-image.advanced.custom-hints). I import the following hints on one of my `@Configuration`s:

```kotlin
class JooqRuntimeHints : RuntimeHintsRegistrar {
    override fun registerHints(hints: RuntimeHints, @Nullable classLoader: ClassLoader?) {
        // Register classes
        hints.reflection().registerType(java.time.Year::class.java)
        hints.reflection().registerField(ReflectionUtils.findField(SQLDataType::class.java, "YEAR")!!)
        println("Finished adding runtime hints for jOOQ")
    }
}
```

However, the error doesn't change despite adding this. I even see "Finished adding runtime hints for jOOQ" in the build logs, so the hint is definitely applied.

Any clue on how to add the proper hint?